# Need an intuitive understanding for this. Topic : Permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

$$nPr = (n-1)Pr + r*(n-1)P(r-1)$$

Why does this formula logically work?

Take $n=5$ and $r=3$ for convenience

Comment: What is incomprehensible about the question? nPr is a standard notation that means permutation(n,r).

Comment: What is a "permutation$(n,r)$"?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter [These things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n) ([Various names](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abz%C3%A4hlende_Kombinatorik#Permutationen,_Variationen_und_Kombinationen) in German.)

Answer (score 0):

You can think $nPr$ as taking $r$ balls one by one from $n$ distinguishable balls.
 There are two (**disjoint**) options, do you take the last ball or you do not take it. The fact that this choices are disjoint is reminiscent of addition, **why?** 
If you dont take it, then you are taking $r$ from the other $n-1.$ If you do, then you could have done it in any of the $r$ draws and the other $r-1$ balls come from the $n-1$ remaining balls. Notice that in the latter you will be multiplying because you have essentially two process linked i.e., when do i take that $n'$th ball and how do i take the remaining ones. This says that you have to multiply the choices. **why?**